# Under-construction roadsign LaTeX (vol1. TAOCP p. xi) Knuth

Tags: symbols

I've searched everywhere on how to include the following symbol found on page 11 of the first volume of *The Art of Computer Programming* by Knuth:

[image]

The dangerous bend symbol is `\dbend` or `\textdbend` but I am unable to find how to include the aforementioned image or symbol, as it seems not to be included in `manfnt` or any other.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such symbol. 
 It is actually an image. 
 You can find it in [`taocpmac`](http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/tex/local/lib/taocpmac.tex).

```latex
\def\beginconstruction{\medbreak
  \begingroup
  \noindent\hang\hangafter=-2
  \smash{\hbox to0pt{\hskip-\hangindent
    \lower\baselineskip\hbox{\epsfbox{\figdir/aux.301}}\hfill}}%
   \sl}
\let\endconstruction=\endgroup
```

The file `\figdir/aux.301` is the symbol you are looking for.

Comment: From what i understand this is some file that Knuth had, I searched his website but could not find the files. would it be possible to get the symbol from somewhere? Or should I just get my own symbol.